# Save byte array to a file PHP

Tags: php, pdf, arrays

I have not been able to find a solution using PHP. Basically, when a user clicks on the "download PDF" link, It will call a PHP function that takes a byte array and parses it as a PDF. I dont know how to go about it. Any help would be great!

EDIT:
I'm getting the "byte array" like this:

```
<?php
$userPDF = $_POST['username'];
$passPDF = $_POST['password'];
$idPDF = 'MO-N007175A';
//PDF Function
$data = array("id" => $idPDF, "username" => $userPDF, "password" => $passPDF);                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                
$ch = curl_init('http://*****.com/****/v1/DealPdf');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1 );                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

The "$result" is supposedly the byte array that looks like this:

```
string(1053240) "[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,54,10,37,211,244,204,225,10,49,32,48,32,111,98
```

..etc.
Basically I need to take what im getting back and save it as a PDF (or any generic file for the matter).

Comment: And this byte array comes from... where? There's no such thing as a 'byte array' in PHP.

Comment: It is coming from a WCF service, and I'm retrieving it from POST.

Comment: So...how do you want to write the object to file?  As a JSON string, I presume?

Comment: @Jack Maney - I added clarification. I dont need to write that JSON object to a file.. That is there just for giving the full idea of how Im doing things. I need to take what I get back from a WCF service, (supposedly a byte array) and save it as a PDF.

Comment: I'm still unclear as to what you mean by "byte array".

Comment: $result is supposed to be the returned byte array. A byte array is an array that has the raw bytes from a PDF file that a WCF service generated.

Comment: For creating PDF's i would recommend TCPDF http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/ it is stable enough to be usable on production, I have used it myself many times, also you should first have a clear view of what the services is returning, can you dump the results of your curl? see what you are getting back, from there try to find the best way to parse it then you can worry about the PDF part, which is in my opinion the less trivial part.

Comment: Please show the result with `var_dump($result);`

Comment: The result of `var_dump($result);` is `string(0) ""` I guess that means Im not actually getting anything back...

Comment: add this curl option:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

Comment: @GiDo Still getting the same result.

Comment: Our .Net programmer is looking into it... the problem may not be mine.

Comment: Ok, so now im getting a string filled with "stuff". `string(1053240) "[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,54,10,37,211,244,204,225,10,49,32,48,32,111,98` ... etc. Now I need to save it as a file, which goes back to my original question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```php
// suppose that the response is a JSON array (look like it)
$bytes = json_decode($results);

$fp = fopen('myfile.pdf', 'wb+');

while(!empty($bytes)) {
    $byte1 = array_shift($bytes);
    $byte2 = array_shift($bytes);
    if(!$byte2) {
      $byte2 = 0;
    }

    fwrite($fp, pack("n*", ($byte1 << 8) + $byte2); // big endian byte order ?
}

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 2):

GiDo's answer will work, but will take very long for large files. I would recommend doing the following:

```
$bytes = json_decode($results);
$bytesStr = pack('C*', ...$bytes);
file_put_contents('myfile.pdf', $bytesStr);
```